# Every compact subset can intersect only finitely many simplices

Tags: compactness, homology-cohomology, simplex, simplicial-complex

Well my question is almost in the title: how can I prove that every compact subset C of |K| can intersect only finitely many simplices, where K is a infinite simplicial complex?

In particular given C I need to find a subcomplex L of K finite s.t. |L| contains C.

I’m not an expert of homology and I need all the proof, because I saw some hints in other questions, but it wasn’t enought.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Construct a simplicial complex with vertices $v$ and $w_n$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots$, and with simplices $(v, w_n)$ for each $n$. Then the compact subset corresponding to the vertex $v$ intersects infinitely many simplices. (Of course that compact subset is still contained in a finite subcomplex.)

Comment: Should your desired complex $L$ be finite? Otherwise let $L=K$: that's a subcomplex whose geometric realization contains $C$.

Comment: Can you provide references to other questions you looked at and also describe your thoughts so far?

Comment: First of all L must be finite (I have just correct the question, thanks)

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I managed to do the first part. Suppose that C intersects infinite many simplices, then it intersects infinite many 0-simplices (points). Take {$x_i$} one for each simplex. Now I consider $U_i=${$x_j s.t j \ne i$}. $U_i$ are closed and their intersection is empty, but there isn’t a finite intersection empty and so I get that C would not be compact that is a contradiction.

Comment: But from here I don’t know how to prove the existence of L

Comment: Well.. maybe it’s enough to take all simplices that it intersects, isn’t it?

Comment: In the case that I presented, the vertex $v$ intersects all of the simplices. Maybe all of the simplices whose interior intersects $C$ (where you take the interior of a $0$-simplex to be itself)?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Now I understand your example and I can’t refute it.. I think you’re right indeed the 0-simplices are close and open so the compact of your example would intersect only the interior of one point

Comment: @JohnPalmieri There’s something wrong. I said that “suppose C intersects infinity many simplices, then it intersects infinity many 0-simplices”, but couldn’t it intersect finitely many points and infinitely many “lines”?

Comment: The example I provided has that feature: the compact subset consisting of the point which is the geometric realization of $v$ intersects infinitely many 1-simplices. The same happens for any compact subset containing that point.

Comment: But I think you can use compactness to show that any compact subset intersects the *interiors* of only finitely many simplices.

Comment: Okay, you’re right :) thanks